# DocuSign: How to receive the signature in the header?

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks, hmac

I'm trying to enable HMAC in DocuSign. I did follow this [tutorial](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-hmac#setting-up-hmac-security-with-your-app), which seams to be updated since the UI in the admin changed, and the documentation does not reflect reality anymore. This is what I have done to enable HMAC:

1. Log-In
2. Click on my avatar
3. Click `Go To Admin`
4. Scrolled down to the section `INTEGRATIONS` in the left side of the menu
5. Clicked `Connect`
6. Clicked `Add Configuration`

   1. I named the configuration
   2. Added the URL to my endpoint
   3. In the `Integration and Security Settings` I selected `Include HMAC Signature - Recommended - Use a hash to verify message authenticity.`
7. Clicked the `Save` button

To receive Webhook messages from DocuSign I'm following this [method](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/webhook-status). But I still don't get the signature in the header.

Since the documentation is outdate I might have missed some crucial setting that is needed to enable the signing off of the Webhook.

I hope someone cane point to my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two different things and mixing them.

The first thing you did was a global connect configuration for the entire account.

The second is for a specific envelope, and it overrides the global connect configuration.

You actually don't need to do that part. Once you have a global connect configuration - all envelopes in this account would be impacted and if you added HMAC - it would be applied to that.
Try to remove this code and just send the envelope regularly and see if you get the HMAC header.